# I'm currently attempting to use the MEXC api to check SPOT account info. Is there a reason I keep getting error code 400?

Tags: r, cryptocurrency

I'm using the following **R** code to try and use MEXC spot v3 api to grab account info. I've already set up an API key that has access to SPOT info/trading. The code I'm using is the following:

```
library(httr)

access.key = "###"
secret.key = "###"

# Generate timestamp in milliseconds
timestamp <- as.character(as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1000)

full.url = paste0("https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=",timestamp)

headers <- c(
  "X-MEXC-APIKEY" = access.key,
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
)

test_get <- httr::GET(full.url, config = add_headers(headers))

test_get$status_code
```

I get a 400 error code when this is run. I believe I'm following all of the instructions from their documentation: https://mexcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/spot_v3_en/#introduction

I'm probably making a simple mistake, but I'm not savvy enough in the API call space to pick out the obvious issue. Any help on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for the Spot requests you have to add signature. The signature should be byte encoded value of all your parameters.

Ex:

1. Prepare query string parameters. (imagine in your case "timestamp=12345678899")
2. Encode it HMAC SHA256 ( "timestamp=12345678899" gives for example "2a7fde34b674")
3. Add last parameter signature=2a7fde34b674
4. Finally your request should be like:
   "https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=12345678899&signature=2a7fde34b674"

Don't hesitate to use Postman of MEXC to check your requests. https://github.com/mexcdevelop/mexc-api-postman